# Regexp to ignore hyphenated words during common word removal pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've got this regular expression which removes common words(`$commonWords`) from a string(`$input`) an I would like to tweak it so that it ignores hyphenated words as these sometimes contain common words.

```
return preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b/i','',$input);
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return preg_replace('/(?<!-)\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b(?!-)/i','',$input);
```

This adds [negative lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) expressions to the start and end of the regex so that a match is only allowed if there is no dash before or after the match.

Comment: Another idea with less advanced features: `/([^-]|^)('.implode('|',$commonWords).')([^-]|$)/i`. Replace with `$1` and trim the resultant string.

Comment: Thanks Tim thanks exactly what I was looking for - worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).'|\w-\w)\b/i','',$input);
```

\w  Any word character (letter, number, underscore)
it'll remove all all the commonwords, AND all the words who've a hyphene.

Comment: I think he wants to ignore, i. e. *not* remove the hyphenated words. (Also you'd have to use `\w+` instead of `\w` for this to work)

Comment: but the best would be for you to include in your common words the hyphene words you want to remove, as you may keep some hyphened words that may be important. You can do a search accross a text sample and see which one are not ok, which are.

Answer (score 0):

```
return preg_replace('/(?<![-\'"])\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b(?![-'"])i','',$input);
```

The above will work if we have more symbols to be escaped.