# perg_replace string reading issue

Tags: php

Here in my case i just want to remove strings from **$input** which are available in **$commonWords** array.

```
$input = "perg-replace my string perge replace";

function removeCommonWords($input){  
  $commonWords = array('my','perge');
  return preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b/','',$input);
}
```

The result I expected was:

"**perg-replace string replace**"

But, result I got from above function was:

"**-replace** string replace"

How to tell perg_replace to read "**perg-replace**" has a single word?

**Update:**

this below code works for me:

```
return preg_replace('/(?<![-\'"])\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b(?![-'"])i','',$input);
```

Comment: Seems this same issue was solved on SO recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946887/regexp-to-ignore-hyphenated-words-during-common-word-removal-pattern

Answer (score 1):

Try this ... ?

```
function removeCommonWords($input) {
  $commonWords = array('my','perge');
  return implode(' ', array_filter(explode(' ', $input), function($word) use ($commonWords) {
    return !in_array($word, $commonWords);
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
// your string.
$str = "perg-replace my string perge replace";

// list of keywords that need to be removed.
$keywords = array('my','perge');

// iterate through the list.
foreach($keywords as $keyword)
{
    $str = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i","",$str);
}

echo $str;
```

Comment: this has some problem, try the below string "perg-replace my string perge replace perg-replace, just-do-it" now add one more keyword in array "just".

Comment: What problem? I created this, tested this and then i posted here.

Comment: check the condition which i have given.

Comment: Ok, i tested this code with this string "perg-replace my string perge replace perg-replace, just-do-it" and i added another keyword which is do and it gave me this result "perg-replace string replace perg-replace, just--it" which is correct. Please explain me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: I need the result as "just-do-it" not "just--it", In my case "just-do-it" need to be considered has one word.

Comment: so just remove do from the array and it will give you that result. I added do additionally in my array that's y i got just--it

Comment: My friend, for example I just gave two words in array. there are lot more in array, your solution not matching exactly. I have updated the solution to my question.

Comment: Ok, without example i can't understand the problem, give me the string and array and your expected result and i will check it

Comment: the function i used was available in this [link](http://snipplr.com/view/6353/) now  my string is simple "do-it" but in above function it gives "-it"

Comment: when i used this in array "do-it", it gave this result  : "perg-replace my string perge replace perg-replace, just-" which is correct.

Comment: in "just-do-id" perge_replace consider "just", "do", "it" has separate word, because of (-), which i don't want. only "just" or "do" or "it" has to be removed when they are separate words

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$input = "perg-replace my string perge replace";
function removeCommonWords($input){  
  $commonWords = array('/my/','/perge/');
  return preg_replace($commonWords,'',$input);
}
echo removeCommonWords($input);
```

Comment: it has problem.. try this string "perg-replace my string perge replace, just-do-it " and add array('/my/','/perge/','/just/')

Comment: The above code is working fine "perg-replace my string perge replace, just-do-it " string as well. if there is a probelm, please explain what it is.

Comment: for me result is coming like "perg-replace string replace, -do-it"

Comment: Okay your expected result on string "perg-replace my string perge replace, just-do-it "?

Comment: can you put the whole code on which you are testing with the string you are checking on and the result you are getting and your expected result as well. Then i will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: @Kathir Maya , try this pattern array array('/my/','/perge/', '/just[^-]/');

Comment: there are so many words in my array. this works for me `return preg_replace('/(?<![-\'"])\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b(?![-'"])i','',$input);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = "perg-replace my string perge replace";

function removeCommonWords($input){  
  $commonWords = array('my','perge');
  return preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b/','',$input);
}

echo removeCommonWords($input);
```